# php generates xml for RSS feed but cannot parse it because the file is php

Tags: php, xml, rss

Hi Im trying to create a news feed using php. I have a php code written which connects to the database and retrieves information which is converted into XML. The file is however a .php and when I try to parse it using google reader it dosen't work because it only reads files which  are XML. Here's my code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$dept = $_GET['dept'];
require_once ("/var/www/html/http/sass/includes/config.inc.php");
require_once ("sass_news.php");
$sassNews = paginate('sass_news', 'sass_news', $numResults, $offset, $order, $condition);
if($sassNews) {
    $xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
    $xml_output .= "<entries>\n";

        foreach($sassNews as $newsDetail){
        $xml_output .= "\t<entry>\n";
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<date>" . $newsDetail->news_start_date . "</date>\n";
        $xml_output .= "\t\t<text>" . $newsDetail->news_body_en . "</text>\n";
        $xml_output .= "\t</entry>\n";
     }

    $xml_output .= "</entries>";

    echo $xml_output;

}
?>
```

Comment: You can probably set the file extension as XML and still have the web server execute the PHP code.  What web server are you using?

Comment: If you are writing XML by bashing together strings, you are probably generating invalid XML. Use an XML library to build XML, and [validate](http://validator.w3.org/feed/)

Answer (score 1):

Try `header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=somename.xml');` at the top of the script. However, if Google Reader is going to allow only URLS which literally end in `.xml`, then you'll need to reconfigure your server to treat .xml files as PHP scripts and rename this script to `whatever.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [RSS specification](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification), that doesn't look like valid markup to me.  It should have an `rss` node, a `channel` node and lots of other goodies.  Also your content-type should be `application/rss+xml`

Comment: To check your feed you can use the Feed validation service: http://validator.w3.org/feed/